# django-localeurl patched reverse doesn't work in unit testing

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, django-1.6, django-localeurl

My app is using django-localeurl. My unit testing were ok in django 1.5.5 but since I moved to django 1.6.2, i have many errors because of status 301 in response.

It seems that this is caused by wrong urls which don't take into account the locale prefix. In other words, when calling `reverse` in a unit test, the usual django `reverse` is called rather than the localeurl `reverse`.

I've checked that the `patch_reverse` is called in the unittest. My call is at the top of my main urls.py. It seems ok.

But for any reason, the django `reverse` is restored by something.

This problem seems to occur only during unit testing. The urls are correctly localized when running the app.

I think the problem correspond to the following issue in django-localeurl : https://bitbucket.org/carljm/django-localeurl/issue/22/test-problem

Does anybody know what can cause this problem (unit testing mechanism have changed in django 1.6, is it the reason?) and how to fix it?

---

**Update**

The problem doesn't occur if I force the following setting

```
TEST_RUNNER = 'django.test.simple.DjangoTestSuiteRunner'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the cause is that the `DiscoverRunner` (new way to run tests in django 1.6) imports the test modules in advance in order to build the list of tests to be run.

As a consequence, the imports of the test modules are executed before the import of settings and urls. Then, the module imports the django `reverse` before it get patched in `urls.py`

My fix is to force the patch at the beginning of my test modules. I think it is not perfect solution but it works.